# Install Tensorflow for python 3 on Deeplens

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, aws-deeplens

I have just started using the Amazon Deeplens device. I got the demo face detection application working. I  have a custom trained tensorflow model (.pb) that I want to deploy on Deeplens. I followed an online guide to create a new project with lambda (python 3.7) and uploaded and imported my model from a s3 bucket. Now, my issue is that I need to install tensorflow on the device for python 3. I tried installing various versions and was even successful it once but I still get an error in the logs saying **Tensorflow Module not found**

I have a couple of questions regarding this:

1. My Lambda has python 3.7 execution environment. Is this correct or should I match the one on deeplens (3.5)?
2. Can I upgrade python on Deeplens to the latest version?
3. If not, what is the Tensorflow version that is supported for python 3.5 on Deeplens and what is the correct command to install it: pip or pip3?

Any help or insight is appreciated.

Comment: If you can change the lambda python version, I would start there. Seems like a quick thing to do, rather than mess about with Deeplens dependencies.

Comment: @JordanSimba Sadly Lambda environment is python 3.6 up. I can't find a 3.5 option.